# Why is my Next.js route handler unable to read the request body from my button component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm not able to read the request body from a route handler in nexjs 13.
This is my button component

```
'use client'

export default function Button() {
    const handleClick = () => {
        const requestOptions = {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.parse('{"hello":"world"}'),
          headers: { "content-type": "application/json"}
        }
        fetch("/api/create", requestOptions)
          .then((res)=>res.json())
          .then((data)=>console.log(data))
          .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
      }
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
  )
}
```

This is my route handler

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
 
export async function POST(request) {
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(request))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(request.body))
  console.log(await request.json())
  
  return NextResponse.json({ "test": "123" });
}
```

I expected the sent body `{"hello": "world"}` to be logged in the console.

This is what is being logged in the console
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj23P.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey there are 2 issues in your code

- When hitting the API using fetch in Button component you are supposed to stringify data and not parse.

```js
   body: JSON.stringify({ hello: 'world' }),
```

- To read data from request body in route.js in next13

```js
  console.log(await request.json())
```

Your entire code should look something like
Button component

```js
'use client';

export default function Button() {
    const handleClick = () => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ hello: 'world' }),
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        };
        fetch('/api/create', requestOptions)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => console.log(data))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    };
    return <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>;
}
```

route.js

```js
export async function POST(request) {
    console.log(await request.json());

    return Response.json({ test: '123' });
}
```

Comment: changing parse to stringify solved it, thank you so much.